# Alternative for "&" in XML

Tags: xml

I am working in XML. I need to send a string like `"BEAUTY & HEALTH"`. The XML won't accept this `"&"`. What would be the alternate for this?

I had tried with `&amp;`, but that is also not working.

```
<graph caption='BEAUTY & HEALTH'>
```

This is the XML Data for the Fusion Chart...

This is what I had given..

```
<graph caption='BEAUTY &amp; HEALTH'></graph>
```

Comment: *How* are you working with the XML?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: With `&amp;`, it should work.

Comment: I had tried with the above solution, Invalid XML Data is coming

Comment: You tried `<graph caption='BEAUTY &amp; HEALTH'>` and it failed? That's impossible.

Comment: No that par is not wellformed. It must be <graph caption='BEAUTY & HEALTH'/>

Comment: @ckuetbach That's irrelevant for the case. There might be a `</graph>` in the part of the code that is not shown.

Comment: Yes, it **might** be in the other part, not shown.

Comment: This is mine...<graph caption='BEAUTY &amp; HEALTH'></graph>

Comment: What error are you getting? There is no reason this should not be working

Comment: I am getting " Invalid XML Data " in my chart...

Comment: Any Stacktraces? That XML **IS** corect if the & is escaped as &amp;

Comment: Hi instead of "&amp;" , if we give "%26" its working fine..

Answer (score 4):

You can write this out as `&amp;` ([this is XML escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping)), or you can use a [CDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256076.aspx) annotation

Here is how it would look:

```
BEAUTY &amp; HEALTH
```

OR

```
<![CDATA[BEAUTY & HEALTH]]>
```

***CDATA can only be used as inner XML, and not for attributes. If it is an attribute, then XML escaping is your only way.

Comment: @Tomalak Yah yah, removed the I believe

Comment: Yeah, much better. :) +1

Comment: Tried with "CDATA"..Not Working....

Comment: @RobinHood CDATA does not apply to attribute values.

Comment: @RobinHood Yes, that is only for inner text. It was not originally made clear about attributes :) Updated my answer with a note

Answer (score 0):

Replace `&` with `&amp;`. `&` is a character entity that needs to be escaped

Comment: Still not working..Getting Invalid XML Data.

Comment: Then you have a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XML-encoded version of the ampersand:  `&amp;`

Comment: That's **XML** encoding.

Comment: You're right, I was sloppy. Thx for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
&#x0026; or &#00038;
```

It really depends on the encoding used.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CDATA structure, as in:

```
 <![CDATA[Beauty & Health]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use `&amp;`

In your case should be:

```
Beauty &amp; Health
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a different problem with you XML.

Use a xml-validator like [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html), to find you problem. **&amp;** is definitly correct within XML-Files. I beleave it may be fileencoding ol malformed XML.

**update**:
First you didn't show, that you are within an attribute. 
Is that xml wellformed? Ist the `<graph />`-Element closed?

```
 <graph caption='BEAUTY & HEALTH'/>
```

Try a [online-validator](http://www.xmlvalidation.com).

If it is a UTF-8 File. Ensure there is no [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Comment: Yes, my XML is correct. The same XML is working for all the other charts...

Comment: if it would be "he same" it would work, too. So it is different.

Comment: I am getting the "&" in one scenario only...so other than this all other are working..

Comment: You are saying your XML is correct but the software is telling you it isn't? I would say the software's opinion is more likely to be correct than yours.